# Create GRF from BMP or HTML5 Canvas pixel data

Tags: javascript, bmp, html5-canvas, zebra-printers

How can I create a Zebra GRF image from HTML5 canvas pixel data or a monochrome BMP file using javascript? I can't find any information on the format of GRF files.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the ZPL programming manual](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_ii_programming2.html).

The ~DG command will tell you the format of the GRF format.  Then it's just some math

Answer (score 0):

You might have to convert this Java code to Javascript, but I came across this and make a command line java app to help.  If you can go to the server at all, then you could probably just invoke this app through shell.

https://github.com/asharif/img2grf

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.